# I am trying to SELECT WHERE IN SELECT, what I am I doing wrong?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * 
FROM `seriallog` WHERE `lastevent` IN
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(' \'', `eventid`, '\''))
        FROM `permissions` WHERE `permissions`.`userpkid` = 1)
```

Comment: What are you expecting to get? What do you actually get?

Answer (score 3):

You are likely trying to compare an int (`lastevent`) to a concatenated string (the result of your subquery).

It is hard to tell without more info, but this probably what you want to do:

```
select * 
from seriallog sl
inner join permissions p on sl.lastevent = p.eventid
where p.userpkid = 1
```

Comment: Might want to write the first line like this: `SELECT sl.*`

Answer (score 2):

The way you've written it, the inner query will return a **string** like `"1, 2, 3"` so only rows in `seriallog` with a `lastevent` column of `"1, 2, 3"` exactly will match.

You're presumably interested in matching any row whose value is in a SET. That's what SQL is designed to do; you don't have to apply any special engineering. The following would work:

```
SELECT *
FROM seriallog WHERE lastevent IN
(SELECT eventid FROM permissions WHERE permissions.userpkid = 1)
```

However, it would be preferable to instead write:

```
SELECT *
FROM seriallog
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM permissions WHERE eventid = seriallog.lastevent AND permissions.userpkid = 1)
```

This allows MySQL to treat the query more like a JOIN, and presumably execute it more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

This is most optimized format for MySQL.  In general MySQL does not love Sub-Queries.

SELECT *
FROM seriallog sl
join permissions p on sl.lastevent=p.eventid
WHERE permissions.userpkid = 1